# Javascript toggle issue

Tags: javascript, dom

This is my script :

```
window.onload = function (){  
   var title = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].id = "heading1";  
   document.getElementById(title).onclick = function (e){  
          var para = this.nextSibling.style.display = 'block';  
          var newVal = (para == "block") ? "none" : "block";  
          alert(newVal);  
   }  
}
```

The result I need is for the alert value to toggle from block to none and back. But I am always getting "none". What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
  var firstH1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
  firstH1.id = "heading1";
  firstH1.onclick = function() {
    var currentValue = this.nextSibling.style.display;
    this.nextSibling.style.display = (currentValue == "none") ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```

Note a few things: I simplified your element fetching because it doesn't make sense to fetch an element, assign it an id, then use that id to find that same element again.

I also switched block/none ordering, because if no style is displayed then it would be blank -- and your first click would assign block to it - and it would not disappear. This way it does.

Comment: it is working fine.  but there is another issue i am getting now. actually in my code i am mentioning the nextSibling is paragraph tag. it should need to show and hide. but it is not working with internet explorer, because it is counting the white space as a charactor..

Comment: how can i ignore the white spaces for internet explorer?

Comment: I think you want to look at nodeType property in order to tell what the nextSibling is - and keep walking through them. I have to ask though - do you know the DOM structure more concretely ahead of time? You're trying to target the first H1 and toggle the next one... that seems awfully specific, but yet very general. Could you not name one "heading1" in the HTML itself, and then have one with id "toggle" or something -- so that you can use getElementById rather than nextSibling? Or is this an exercise that is meant to make you aware of cross-browser JavaScript differences?

Answer (score 2):

Well, para will always be "block", and therefore newVal will always be "none".  So that behavior is expected.  What are you trying to do?  you are not toggling the property with your curent code.

Comment: (overlapped with Doug...assuming you are trying to toggle, his code will work)

Comment: Woo! I'm finally allowed to comment. Yes, the problem is that you were assigning a value likely when you were just trying to store the value in a shorter variable name for readability.